# firewalld and localhost address translation

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, firewalld

I have a server with red hat 7.1 which has two ip addresses, a public one available on internet on interface bond1 and a private one on the corporate lan on interface bond0.

I have apache 2.4 offering web pages on internet, and a reverse proxy configured on it to forward some requests to a tomcat server running on the same machine. This tomcat server has two application running on it and one of them accept connections only from 127.0.0.1, and those requests usually comes from the other tomcat application.

The problem is that the requests that one tomcat application make to the others get the private ip address (the one on bond0) and thus get rejected by tomcat (403 error code). If I disable firewalld with systemctl stop firewalld, everything works as expected.

I know that the address gets translated from 127.0.0.1 to 172.30.xx.xx because I see from the tomcat logs.

Now I can't change anything on the tomcat side, I just want to know who and why is translating this address and fix it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those of you who comes here, it was the masquerading.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-masquerade
```

and it works.

Zone public because the configuration described in the question wasn't the active one, and both bond0 and both1 were added to zone public